# How to pass pytest fixture to tests

Tags: python, selenium

I have a PyTest fixture to initialize a driver and stored in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture
def browser():
    ...
    yield driver

    driver.quit()
```

How to pass the fixture to test to get the driver?

```
def test_one():
    ...
```

Is the could be in scope?

Comment: It seems you're just starting with the pytest. If you are looking for some POM structure examples, it could be easily found on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the fixture to the test, you simply use it as a test function argument if it stored in confttest.py:

```
def test_one(browser): 
 …
```

Also, for future usage make sure you’ll use the correct scope. [Docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session)